# Matrix within a list? or just Matrix?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have the following scenario

An Account table related to many Opportunity table 
Opportunity table has two columns Divison and Services 
I need to display the matrix of Division (row) and Services (column) for each account 
I would need to display account name before matrix, and each matrix on a new page.

I have a list and grouped the list by accountid but when I ran the report I got the error : "Detail members can only contain static inner members"

To work around I gave up to using a list, just a matrix.

Then I grouped the matrix on accountid and able to get a matrix per account on a separate page 
However I was not able to get the name of the account displayed before each matrix no matter what I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the answers.

What I did in the end was to create a List w/ data source select accountid, accountname  and grouped by the accountid. I show the account name in the list.

then I created a sub report where I have a matrix for the division (row) services(column) and included subreport in the list

the sub report gets the account id from list and queries all opportunities for divisions and services

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, you can have the detail member only at the most inner tablix. I think likewise it's the same for matrix.
Try the following:
- add a group for accountId
- add a parent COLUMN-group and group by accountId also
- now change the inner grouping to division.

Just as approach, go on like this for Service group

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following:

Create a List ... grouped based on Account:
Text box with List `=First(Fields!AccountNameOrID.Value)`
Matrix w/ Opportunity information filtered based on the AccountId of the List. (delete the detail grouping add a row and create your own grouping) Page Break after each section you want to have a page break on.

I ran into this issue before and took a while to figure out that I had to get rid of the Detail row within the Matrix and add my own row and grouping.

Hope that helps.